# Find cycle time of pipeline processor

Tags: pipelining

a program contains 4000 instructions. The clock rate of a non pipelined processor is 100MHz and CPI is 2. find time taken by a non-pipelined processor to complete a program ,instruction latency and throughput . part(b) the above non pipeline processor  has modified into pipelined processor  which has 4 stages. If the data path is evenly divided among the pipeline stages and pipeline latches with 0.5ns latency. find the cycle time, instruction latency and throughput of the pipelined processor

I gained cycle time as 80 microseconds, instruction latency as 20ns and throughput as 50 ins/microseconds. How I find clock cycle time of pipeline processor?

Comment: Oops, I picked the wrong close reason. Here's the right one: This isn't a programming question as defined in the [help/on-topic].